# Правильная аннотация типов в цепочке промисов

Tags: typescript, инспекция-кода, promise

Вопрос очень простой: нет ли в приведённом ниже коде ошибок в аннотации типов?

```
async function fetchAllRequiredData(): Promise<void> {

  return Promise.all([
      // эти данные независимые; их можно загрузить параллельно
      this.fetchDataSet1a(),
      this.fetchDataSet1b()
  ])
      .then((): Promise<void> => {

        if (someCondition) {
          // эти данные зависимы от предыдущих; возможно их и не нужно загружать вовсе, но в любом случае, нужно правильно просигнализировать о том, что промис успешно завершен.
          return this.fetchDataSet2()
              .then((): Promise<void> => {
                return Promise.resolve();
              })
              .catch((): Promise<void> => {
                return Promise.reject();
              });
        }

        return Promise.resolve();
      })
      .catch((): Promise<void> => {
        return Promise.reject();
      })
}
```

Я знаю, что `async` функция возвращает промис - если не сделать это явно, то JavaScript при выполнении сам обернёт возвращаемый результат в промис (если ничего не возвращать - это будет Promise.

Все функции группы `fetchDataSet` также возвращают промисы (пускай они будут пустыми). Затруднения вызывают функции в then и catch. Если посмотреть определения типов к ней, то это какая-то жесть:

```
then<TResult1 = T, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: T) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | undefined | null, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>) | undefined | null): Promise<TResult1 | TResult2>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Код выше можно сократить до

```
function fetchAllRequiredData() {
    return Promise.all([
        // эти данные независимые; их можно загрузить параллельно
        this.fetchDataSet1a(),
        this.fetchDataSet1b(),
    ]).then(() => {
        if (someCondition) {
            // эти данные зависимы от предыдущих; возможно их и не нужно загружать вовсе, но в любом случае, нужно правильно просигнализировать о том, что промис успешно завершен.
            return this.fetchDataSet2();
        }
    });
}
```

без потери смысла и функциональности.

В [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1013679/272582) немного прояснены особенности работы с промисами (это про chaining и flattening). Возможно, это именно то что вызывает затруднения.